# R# extract method and replace occurrences

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, refactoring, resharper

Maybe it is silly question and there is easy way to do this.

Consider this code-snippet:

```cs
Page firstPage = Controller.Get(Pages.FIRST_NAME);
if (firstPage != null)
{
    PagePath pagePath = firstPage.GetFullPath();
    string pagePathName = Path.Render(pagePath);
    buffer.AppendFormat("Path: {0} .", pagePathName);
}
Page secondPage= Controller.Get(Pages.SECOND_NAME);
if (secondPage != null)
{
    PagePath pagePath = secondPage.GetFullPath();
    string pagePathName = Path.Render(pagePath);
    buffer.AppendFormat("Path: {0} .", pagePathName);
}

if (includeHeader)
{
    Page page = Controller.Get(Pages.HEADER_NAME);
    if (page != null)
    {
        PagePath pagePath = page.GetFullPath();
        string pagePathName = Path.Render(pagePath);
        buffer.AppendFormat("Path: {0} .", pagePathName);
    }
}
if (includeFooter)
{
    Page page = Controller.Get(Pages.FOOTER_NAME);
    if (page != null)
    {
        PagePath pagePath = page.GetFullPath();
        string pagePathName = Path.Render(pagePath);
        buffer.AppendFormat("Path: {0} .", pagePathName);
    }
}
```

I want to refactor this code, because it has duplicated code block.
So first I want to use "Extract method" on the fragment:

```cs
PagePath pagePath = page.GetFullPath();
string pagePathName = Path.Render(pagePath);
buffer.AppendFormat("Path: {0} .", pagePathName);
```

This is obvious that this code has 3 other code block like this. If you use "Find Matching Clones in Solution" you get 1 Exact Match and 2 Strong Match.

But when I apply extract method, it's extract only this selected code, not all occurrences. I want to change all occurrences.

**Is it possible to do this automatically not by hand?** Eventually it's refactoring tool so it should do this by it self.

I have R# 8.2 and VS 2012.

I've try to find any information about this, and find out that this topic was discuss in R# Community in 2006 ([Enhancement to Extract method - replace occurances of extracted code](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5179362#5179362)).